# Why jquery is not loaded from vite in my blade view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vite

I made a simple blade view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> @yield('title') | MY APP</title>
        @vite([
            'resources/css/style.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
           ])
</head>
<body>
<nav id="deltaNavbar">
    <div class="logoContainer "><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><img src="{{ url('/logo.png')  }}"></a>  </div>
</nav>

@section('main')
@show

    @vite([
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
            'resources/js/main.js'
           ])
</body>
</html>
```

That is loaded via this route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
});
```

And I install jquery, bootstrap and font-awesome via npm:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "nodejs": "^0.0.0"
    }
}
```

I did the nessesary installations as well:

```
npm install
```

And I used this `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/style.css',
                'resources/js/main.js',
                'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

But once I run `npm build` and visit the homepage I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js.
```

Any idea why that does happen? I have no indication why.

Comment: in `main.js`, import the `/jquery.js`, then in blade just use the @vite for `main.js`

Answer (score -1):

I think you have installed the jQuery properly. Let us proceed one by one. Lets pick and fix `jQuery` first.

Can you try by updating your `resources/js/app.js`:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

and then in your `main.blade.php` update the following:

```html
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

Also you update the `vite.config.js` as follows:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Please let me know if it works for `jQuery`. Then we can do the same for `bootstrap` also.